# How to split datetime?

Tags: python, django

I am sending sms to user after successful transaction,in that sms i am adding date.

During sending sms taking that date from database, as that is datetime field it gives me date up to nano seconds while i want only date of transaction, how can i split it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think date instance method should do the job -

```
date = transaction_datetime.date() # assuming transaction_datetime is a datetime object
```

Reference - https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html